# Add new form item to antd dynamic form list outside of the form

Tags: reactjs, forms, dynamic, antd, addition

Based on this code snippet, I would like to reach and trigger the `add` property outside of the form. Any idea how can I do it?

```
<Form form={form} initialValues={initialValues} onFinish={onSubmit}>
  <Form.List>
    {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
      <div>
        {fields.map(field => (
          <Form.Item {...field}>
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  </Form.List>
  // I don't want use this button here, inside the form list. 
  // I want invoke the add function from outside.
  <Button type="link" onClick={() => add()}>
    Add
  </Button>
</Form>
// Or maybe from here
<Button type="link" onClick={() => add()}>
  Add
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. What I did is extracted everything under `{(fields, { add, remove }) => (` into external component.

Then exposed an `addItem` method from it using `useImperativeHandle` that just calls `add` action from antd `Form.List`

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  addItem() {
    actions.add()
  },
}))
```

And then call this method from external component via ref like this:

```
const fieldsRef = useRef<ItemsListInteface>(null)

return (
  <Form.List name={name}>
    {(fields, actions, { errors }) => (
      <ItemsList
        ref={fieldsRef}
        fields={fields}
        actions={actions}
        errors={errors}
      />
    )}
  </Form.List>

  <Button type="link" onClick={() => fieldsRef.current?.addItem()}>
    Add
  </Button>
)
```